# Reg exp functionality breaking password strength function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following this [tutorial](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Password-Strength-validation-example-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx), I have adjusted the script so rather than displaying a gradient progress bar, a block progress bar is displayed using `li` items like so:

```
<ul id="passwordStrength">
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
</ul>
```

Depending on what criteria has been filled, the first `li` item will fill with the colour red, then second `li` will fill if they used an uppercase character or special character etc. until the user has met all the criteria and the 4th `li` item is filled a dark colour green.

I have two issues (I know I should keep each post to a single issue).

First is the colouring of the li items. When the user removes text from the input, I want the colouring to reset to the default value of `#dcdcdc`.

Second is an inconsistent behaviour in the reg exp. When I enter a special character before a number, it then only logs special characters, so the counter never reaches 4, so the statement for the strength bar to turn green and fill the final `li` item never happens.

***Question/s***

How can I get the colours for each `li` item to reset to grey if the user removes input, thus the criteria is filled?

Why when I enter a special character does it then persist on only registering special characters, even if I press a number?

Apologies for asking 2 questions.

```
$('#password').bind('keyup', function(){

    if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        password_li.css('background', '#DDD');
        return;
    }

        var regex = new Array();
    regex.push("[A-Z]"); //Uppercase Alphabet.
    regex.push("[a-z]"); //Lowercase Alphabet.
    regex.push("[0-9]"); //Digit.
    regex.push("[$@$!%*#?&]"); //Special Character.

    var passed = 0;

    //Validate for each Regular Expression.
    for (var i = 0; i < regex.length; i++) {
        if (new RegExp(regex[i]).test($(this).val())) {
            console.log(regex[i]) //here I can see what expression is being entered
            passed++;
        }
    }


    //Validate for length of Password.
    if (passed > 2 && $(this).val().length > 8) {
        passed++;
    }

    switch(passed) {
        case 0:
        break;
        case 1:
        console.log('red')
            $(password_li[0]).css('background', '#e30613'); //red
        break;
        case 2:
        console.log('amber')
            $(password_li[1]).css('background', '#f9b233'); //amber
        break;
        case 3:
        console.log('green')
            $(password_li[2]).css('background', '#53ab58'); //green
        break;
        case 4:
        console.log('dark green')
            $(password_li[3]).css('background', '#53ab58');
        break;


    }

})
```

***UPDATE***

Resolved issue with resetting colours to grey. Just the reg exp issue now

Comment: The problem is that you add to `passed` when any the test is validated but you can't tell which ones were really passed...

Comment: Ok. Can I ask what your solution would be?

Comment: What I would do is turn `passed` into a boolean array and add assign the return of `new RegExp(regex[i]).test($(this).val())` to each correspondant array element 'passed[i] = new RegExp(regex[i]).test($(this).val())` and `if (passed > 2 && $(this).val().length > 8)` then check all the values in `passed[idx]` to be true and change the `$(password_li[idx]).css(...` as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to count to 5, not 4 as you have 5 tests including length.
The additional debug here shows it's working fine:

```
$password="aA$"
var passed = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < regex.length; i++) {
    if (new RegExp(regex[i]).test($password)) {
        passed++;
        console.log(regex[i]+" passed "+passed)         
    } else {
        console.log(regex[i]+" failed")
    }
}
console.log("Total "+passed);
```

Result:

```
[A-Z] passed 1
[a-z] passed 2
[0-9] failed
[$@$!%*#?&] passed 3
Total 3
```

Comment: Case 0 is null, and for the 4 li items, there are 4 criterias. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You have 4 regex criteria and one length criteria hence you have 5 "levels" of success? If you meet all requirements the total will be ultimately be 5. You don't have a case for that so will be suggesting "complete" with only 4 out of 5 criteria met. And your length criteria is only met if > 2 of the others are met. So if you meet all 4 regex and length you get an unhandled case (5), and you can only get 4 if you type enough characters without meeting one of the regex but whilst hitting 8 in length.

Comment: You sir, are completely right. Feel a bit of a fool now. Thank you for time and explanation